# как изменить z-index углов объекта на холсте fabric.js?

Tags: css, fabricjs

Фон накрывает объекты сверху через setOverlayImage , углы для растягивания не видно. Можно ли как то изменить у них z-index ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код которым вы пытаетесь это реализовать .Никто не обязан это воссоздавать

Comment: А вы чо ясновидящий, если нет то даже плохо анализируете ответы.

Comment: Совет на будущее : если хотите чтоб вам помогли  то постарайтесь быть точнее,и приведите пример ваших решений.Ото программисты они ленивые ,и сидеть все это воспроизводить и дебажить за вас скорее всего не будут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решился, нужно было добавить controlsAboveOverlay : true

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      controlsAboveOverlay : true
    });

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]